# How to make the ends of a div or section slant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using normal row and column code in a div which is given below :

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly for having a div like a rectangle or a box. At both the ends.

How to make the ends of the div slant at some angle?

I've added the link to the image for reference and the link to the website I'm referring too.

[image]

[This is the link to the website I'm referring.](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_54794/)

Comment: That example uses images, but you can do it with CSS, there's a lot of different ways. You can use `border`, a `pseudo-element`, and other ways. Check `transform: rotate();` on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: That website splits it into two images, then uses `::before` and `::after` to set them as background images. If your ever unsure how they do it, open up dev tools and look.

Comment: Here's a Fiddle using `border` in pseudo-elements, I think it's what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/zsvy1yb0/